# User Login/logout accounting to enforce max session time?

Tags: linux, macos, radius, accounting, remote-login

I'd like to set up a home system where users (i.e., house kids) have a given max time of computer use per day/week/whatever, and after that time they're logged off. They should be able to log in and out as wanted as long as they still have "credit time".

Initial thoughts would be to set up some kind of remote user login based on my always-on Mac Mini (or Synology NAS) that does logon/logoff accounting (some kind of Radius server? Which?)

Client computers would ideally be Linux or OSX (I'd rather havoid having to maintain a Windows computer, if I don't have to, having weaned out myself out of it a while ago)

I've been looking around at how to configure things, but I'm not clear if the max session time is enforced somehow - looking for tips/tricks/experience on setting up something similar...

Answer (score 0):

I see no reason for no using SElinux and Bash. You can use /etc/security/limits.conf to setup some limits. SElinux can guarantee nobody can edit it, even root. You can add TMOUT=300 or something like that in /etc/profile in order to logout after some time at login. Plus you can use Bash, too, for example to do something at a point of time:

`H=$(date +%H)
if (( 8 <= 10#$H && 10#$H < 13 )); then 
    echo between 8AM and 1PM
elif (( 13 <= 10#$H && 10#$H < 23 )); then 
    echo between 1PM and 11PM
else
    echo go to bed
fi`